# Docker compose database url environment variable for flask app

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, environment-variables

Trying to use docker-compose.yml instead of starting the containers separately like so:

```
docker container run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes -e MYSQL_DATABASE=currency -e MYSQL_USER=currency -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=currency mysql/mysql-server:5.7


docker run --name currency -d -p 8000:5000 --rm --link mysql:dbserver -e DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://currency:currency@dbserver/currency currency:latest
```

When run separately, the flask app correctly finds the DATABASE_URL and uses mysql db.

The docker-compose.yml file which I used is below:

```
version: "2"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
        environment:
            - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD:yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE:currency
            - MYSQL_USER:currency
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD:currency
    currency:
        build: .
        links:
            - "mysql:dbserver"
        ports:
            - "8000:5000"
        environment:
            - DATABASE_URL:"mysql+pymysql://currency:currency@dbserver/currency"
```

When I use docker-compose.yml, it is not using the mysql db. I believe for some mistake in docker-compose.yml, the flask app is not able see the environment variable "DATABASE_URL". What is going wrong in the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1):

First: make sure to *not* use **[links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)**

> The `--link` flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use **[user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks)** to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using `--link`.
> One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with --link is sharing environmental variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment variables between containers in a more controlled way.

Second, do a `docker exec -it currency bash` to open a session in your currency container, and do an `echo "DATABASE_URL='${DATABASE_URL}'"` in it, to check the environment variable has been set.

Finally, check in your case if this is an ordering issue (currency starting *before* the database is fully up)

See "[Control startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)".
For instance:

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```